# pbjs command not found after installing pbjs in project

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, backend, protobuf.js

I am working on an ionic project using protobuf and I already installed protobuf. Bow i want to install the pbjs tool. I did so in the project directory using npm install pbjs. But when i use pbjs followed by valid arguments, I am given -bash: command not found 'pbjs'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because you haven't installed pbjs globally, You can install it globally with

`npm install -g pbjs`
Or you could even access it from the project directory without installing it globally by doing 
`node_modules/.bin/pbjs <command you want to execute>`
Since you have already installed it in your project dir.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was it!